# How to find a value in a list of dictionaries and return a specific key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of gpg keys. each in their own dictionary. I want to search though this list of dictionary s by one value 'foo@foo.bar' and return the value of the key d['keyid'] in the same dictionary. Here's what i have.:

```
>>> import gnupg
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG()
>>> email = 'foo@foo.bar'
>>> keyIn = gpg.gen_key_input(name_real = 'works' , name_email = 
>>> email,key_type='RSA',key_length=1024)
>>> key = gpg.gen_key(keyIn)
>>> klist = gpg.list_keys()
>>> print klist
[{'dummy': u'', 'keyid': u'CF7BBCC34CCC28A0', 'expires': u'1420347600', 'subkeys': [], 'length': u'1024', 'ownertrust': u'u', 'algo': u'1', 'fingerprint': u'5D917845BF81E47403265380CF7BBCC34CCC28A0', 'date': u'1388889639', 'trust': u'u', 'type': u'pub', 'uids': [u'works <foo@foo.bar>']}, {'dummy': u'', 'keyid': u'865F4A95D4999F17', 'expires': u'1420347600', 'subkeys': [], 'length': u'1024', 'ownertrust': u'u', 'algo': u'1', 'fingerprint': u'C081E6552B027E2DA4143852865F4A95D4999F17', 'date': u'1388890408', 'trust': u'u', 'type': u'pub', 'uids': [u'works <foo@foo.bar>']}, {'dummy': u'', 'keyid': u'1F6A4AEA477EFBD6', 'expires': u'1420347600', 'subkeys': [], 'length': u'1024', 'ownertrust': u'u', 'algo': u'1', 'fingerprint': u'B306139A3D740CECA71D9F281F6A4AEA477EFBD6', 'date': u'1388890595', 'trust': u'u', 'type': u'pub', 'uids': [u'works <foo@foo.bar>']}]
```

Now here is the functions that i have tried:

```
def idfind(klist):
    global email
    for k in klist:
        if email in k.items():
            return k

def idfind(l):
    global email
    for d in l:
        if any(d[email]):
            return d['keyid']

def idfind(l, val):
    for d in l:
        for v in d[k]:
            if val in v:
                return d['keyid']

def idfind(lst,val):
    for d in lst:
        if isinstance(d,dict):
            for k,v in d.items():
                if val in k:
                    return d['keyid']

def idfind(lst,val):
    for d in lst:
        if isinstance(d,dict):
            for k,v in d.items():
                if val == v:
                    return d['keyid']
```

All of the functions either return `None` or an error. How can i get this to work. and why have i failed so far. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and `any` function, like this

```
key = 'foo@foo.bar'
print [d["keyid"] for d in klist if any(key in uid for uid in d["uids"])]
```

**Output**

```
[u'CF7BBCC34CCC28A0', u'865F4A95D4999F17', u'1F6A4AEA477EFBD6']
```

Comment: That worked great! thank you. So i should have specified the 'key' for the value i was searching for?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, may work:

```
def idfind(klist):
    for d1 in a:
        for e in d1['uids']:
            if email in e:
                print d1['keyid']
```

**Output:**

```
CF7BBCC34CCC28A0
865F4A95D4999F17
1F6A4AEA477EFBD6
```

Comment: Also worked! Going by what you wrote I didnt nest it far enough?

Comment: Your **third** attempt was very close to my approach, you just needed to change `d[k]` with `d['uids']` and remember, that when you use **return**, the function will return just the value it found, and won't continue with the rest of the loop.

Comment: @Matt Welcome to stack overflow! It's beneficial to upvote helpful answers, and accept the one that fits your needs :)

Comment: @Christian Thanks for the extra tip. didnt know that :)

Comment: @vinod Thank you . I would upvote if i could. Need more rep first.:)